# Call validation event on Vue Formulate manually?

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

I have a Vue Formulate form that is getting repopulated from data that I fetch from an API. After my data is set inside my form, vue formulate does not detect that my data is already inserted. As soon as I type a single character in one of the formfields my validation is correct, and vue formulate parsed all values.

Is it possible to trigger form validation after data from an api is inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I updated the formulate package and now its working without triggering any events.